# how to resolve java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Log cat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.yourpackagename, PID: 8102
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yourpackagename/com.yourpackagename.TestActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.checkMode(ContextImpl.java:2134)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:354)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:349)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)
                                                     at com.basewin.utils.GlobalTransData.init(GlobalTransData.java:74)
                                                     at com.basewin.services.ServiceManager.init(ServiceManager.java:70)
                                                     at com.yourpackagename.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:25)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: GlobalTransData.java:74->   this.mPrefs = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences("global_data", 1);

Comment: TestActivity.java:25-> ServiceManager.getInstence().init(getApplicationContext());

Comment: GlobalTransData.java:43-> mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: A) dont put more information into comments ... always always always add stuff into your question B) but before writing up a question, put that exception message into you favorite search engine. It took me **less** time to find that DUP than it took me to read your question

Comment: Sorry, I do not have much experience with forums and I have been struggling with this exception for some time and I do not see how to solve it.

Comment: Simply read the duplicated answer. What you are trying to do **is not supported** any more. You dont have global writeable files. End of story. You have to step back, look at your requirements and find another way to do what needs to be done.

Comment: This project is part of an already existing project that works fine on the device, so I want to change it for other purposes, but I'm conditioned by this line: ServiceManager.getInstence () .init (getApplicationContext ()); Which calls the others mentioned above and actually initializes device server here.

Comment: Lets put it that we: if some more Android guru comes by and states he has a solution; I will have no problem re-opening this question. But until then, I will things like they are.

Comment: *"This project is part of an already existing project that works fine on the device"* - I think that the point is that the code *won't* work on newer devices.  And the reason that it won't work is that the feature the old code was relying has been deemed to be **insecure**.  If you want that code to work on newer devices, you will need to change the part that relies on this feature.